Do workplaces typically have protections to counter the incredible access IT has?
To make a very long story short, I have an IT technician who frequently calls to chew me out over IT tickets that don't meet her approval. I found most of the complaints completely unreasonable--I have my duties and if I were to stop and spend 30 minutes to diagnose each problem first, it would create safety issues, and I would be fired for neglecting my responsibilities. It wasn't until one day I was out on sick leave when I finally received her chewing-out in E-mail form, and I had proof to give to my boss, and a very unreasonable complaint it was.
Now I have a very angry IT technician who doesn't want to work with me. I realize IT has a lot of power, they have passwords, access to drives, virtual and physical access, so I think it wouldn't be hard for them to take revenge if they were inclined, ex. planting evidence. I don't know that they would, but wonder, are there protections typically in place to prevent IT from abusing that power? I am in a workplace with about 3,000 employees.

In a company of 3000 people, a typical IT technician will not have elevated access permissions to very much at all, and everything will have an audit log anyway.

They don’t actually have passwords. They just have the ability to reset passwords. Which create an audit trail.

VTC - This is fundamentally not a workplace question, but an IT security question.

In one company, important people used to get sent on holiday for a week at a random time once a year, and then their work, access, logs etc. would be examined. No warning. Say Wednesday evening you are told "good bye, come back next Thursday morning" with no pre-warning. More difficult with people working from home.

As Donald says, they have absolutely no access to your passwords. If well organised they can reset your password, but not without that being logged under the name of the IT person.

This question oddly dodges any concrete context about the kind of tickets you are creating and the feedback you're getting. I'm aware your focused question is on whether IT is able to frame you for things you didn't do but the healthier workplace attitude here would be to explore the interpersonal friction you're experiencing and assess who is being reasonable here. You don't do that by omitting the specifics of that friction.

@Flater First, I have to put in tickets for a lot of people, including many children, who don't have access or the ability to enter tickets. Second, the IT gets angry whenever I put in a ticket they found easy to fix, but as my supervisor agreed, it isn't my job to diagnose issues. In fact, my supervisor put in tickets similar to the ones I got chewed out over.

It's not guaranteed, but IT companies of this size should have massive surveillance systems, writing log files about who does what, when and where.
Nobody should have all the passwords, except for a couple of super-adminstrators, and your IT Technician doesn't sound like one of those.
This is not just for stopping some angry colleague from making monkey business regarding you and your fellow employees, it's plain safety for employees not being tempted by this 'incredible power' to use it for personal gain. Just think of the IT-systems in banks and the like. And money is not the only valuables needing protection from criminals.
You are afraid there should be planted evidence. That would be a very serious crime, and I believe it's very unlikely someone will take this path, however angry they are.

"Nobody should have all the passwords, except for a couple of super-adminstrators" Or even better, nobody has all the passwords; in particular, "ability to do priviliged action" and "ability to read priviliged action logs" live with different people. Not always possible in a small company but certainly possible in a company with 3k people.


Now I have a very angry IT technician who doesn't want to work with me.

It sounds like she didn't like working with you ever.
I think I would first try to make sure you have a properly functioning relationship. It sounds like what's happening is that you're somehow dumping a load of tickets on her that somehow pass through your hands but which don't ultimately originate with you, and which you are not triaging properly in her view.
The fact that you're busy or have other duties isn't in itself a good reason to cause regular hassle for other staff, especially if they are more distant than you are from the coal face where the problem is, and if it's regularly discovered that you were the proper person to have resolved the problem.
I'm only surmising this possibility, and of course you might be being oblique to avoid identifying yourself to colleagues, but it does very much sound like you're not meeting minds about what amount or manner of use of the central IT function is reasonable, and that it's a recurrent difference.

I think it wouldn't be hard for them to take revenge if they were inclined, ex. planting evidence. I don't know that they would, but wonder, are there protections typically in place to prevent IT from abusing that power? I am in a workplace with about 3,000 employees.

I think the fear of this is probably more prevalent than the occurrence, and in a workplace with 3,000 staff, the people handling tickets are unlikely to be the most senior IT staff with the fewest controls and least routine supervision.
Relatively low-grade IT staff may have wide access to information, so they can be unexpectedly powerful in that regard, but the facility and skill to fraudulently modify data in a way that appears plausible, causes serious harm to others, and leaves no trace or suspicion of their own criminality to any other person, is generally out of reach.
There are prominent cases where computer records have been falsified to the detriment of others, but this typically involves the connivance of the organisation and the entire IT function, and the target is not typically the individual victim.
The usual aim of individual dishonesty, is to quietly view or modify business records for personal gain.

Because you can't directly control what a person in IT does, your best option is to document why they might do it. Otherwise it is a pure he said/she said. Mitigate the risk if and when other people review the situation if it goes sideways - meaning what you fear actually occurs.
Start with kindness. Then escalate.
There is no going back if you choose to start, but if you are scared of them then consider getting your concerns on record.
Please keep in mind that this is your life and career, random internet people don't bear the consequences of any actions. We can only tell you what we did in our own similar experiences.
Examples:
Kindness:
"It is interesting that you say that. As a non-IT person with my focus on my duties, what could I have done differently" in your own words.
Escalate:
With enough of these on the record, complain to both your's and their manager. "As you know, I am not an IT person, when I am requesting support I am respectful of everyone's time involved. Attached are several emails that are personal attacks towards me. I am asking for help in this situation. Frankly, I am concerned with this person's behavior towards me."

This isn't an answer to the question that was asked :)

@Erik I clarified the answer. When someone doesn't have direct control mitigate the risk.


Do workplaces typically have protections to counter the incredible
access IT has?

Organizations should be concerned about insider threats. They counter the risk by making sure they hire correctly, they use logging systems to allow investigations, and they distribute the power across multiple people.
While this is hard to do for a very small organization, the size you work for (3000 people) means they don't have to concentrate all the power into a handful of people.
In the non-IT world one person doesn't control the money. The person deciding that funds should be spent is not the person that writes the check, or the person that records the expenses, and somebody else audits everything.
